# Remove stop words from sentence

Tags: javascript, json, regex, reactjs, stop-words

I have a sentence but this sentence was split for every space.

My datas output like this

```
const escapeRE = new RegExp(/([/\?""])/g);
const myDatas = data.map(des => des.Sentence.toLowerCase().replace(escapeRE, '').split(' '));

[ [ 'yes',
'keep',
'go',
'apple',
'tabacco',
'javascript',
'no',
'uhh',
'omg',
'hi.' ],
['say',
'hello',
'me',
'allright',
'maybe',
'mi',
'say.' 
....] ]
```

And than i have a stop words `JSON` file.

The contents of stop words `JSON` file

```
['yes',
'hi',
'so',
'say',
'me',
'uhh',
'omg',
'go',
'hello',
'hi' 
 ...]
```

So I want to remove stop words from array sentence. 
I want pure sentence, without stop words.
`stopwords` Defination;

```
const stopwords = require('./stop_words.json');
```

So what should I do ? I don't have any idea. I was try `myDatas.replace('stopwords', '' )` function but it's useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ES6 solitions

```
  myDatas.map(des => des.filter(word => stopWords.indexOf(word) < 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Array prototype like this:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(stopwords) {
    return this.filter(function(word) {
        var punctuationlessWord = word.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "");
        return stopwords.indexOf(punctuationlessWord) < 0;
    });
};
```

And usage:

```
myDatas.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
  theArray[index] = theArray[index].diff( stopwords );
});
```

```js
var myDatas = [ [ 'yes',
'keep',
'go',
'apple',
'tabacco',
'javascript',
'no',
'uhh',
'omg',
'hi.' ],
['say',
'hello',
'me',
'allright',
'maybe',
'mi',
'say.'] ];

var stopwords = ['yes',
'hi',
'so',
'say',
'me',
'uhh',
'omg',
'go',
'hello',
'hi'];

Array.prototype.diff = function(stopwords) {
    return this.filter(function(word) {
  var punctuationlessWord = word.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
  return stopwords.indexOf(punctuationlessWord) < 0;
 });
};

myDatas.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
  theArray[index] = theArray[index].diff( stopwords );
});

console.log(myDatas);
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved your case. This is ES6 solutions.  I guess best practise 
for this question for me  `myDatas.map(des => des.filter(word => stopWords.indexOf(word) < 0));`

Comment: If ES6 is supported then it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using jQuery grep function. You can use like below.

```
    var withoutStopWords = jQuery.grep(myDatas, function(element, index){
  return stopwords.indexOf(element)<0;
                  });
```

Javascript example

```
var filtered=myDatas.filter(function(e){return this.indexOf(e)<0;},stopwords);
```

Comment: But I'm using only react es6.

Comment: Maybe like this following ES6 syntax: `let filtered = myDatas.filter(e => this.indexOf(e) < 0, stopwords);`

Answer (score 0):

First thigh that got on my mind is that you can create recursive function that will iterate over the sentence array and just check if the sentence word is in `stopWords` array something like this:

```
function removeStopWords(sentenceArray, stopWords, result = []) {
    sentenceArray.forEach((sentence) => {
        if (Array.isArray(sentence)) {
            result = removeStopWords(sentence, stopWords, result);
        } else if (!stopWords.includes(sentence)) {
            result = result.concat(sentence)
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```